# How to match two column values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, matching, calculated-columns

I have a SQL Server table `Author_Areas` as:

```
aid         Category_2005...Category_2007...Category_2014       Rank
--------------------------------------------------------------------
677         8               19              0                   1
677         11              0               0                   2
677         12              0               0                   3
...
...
```

How can we match `Category_2005` column (similarly also other columns) of table `Author_Areas` with table `CoAuthor_Areas` which is as:

```
co_aid      Category_2005...Category_2007...Category_2014       Rank
--------------------------------------------------------------------
901706      11              5               0                   1
901706      8               19              0                   2
901706      12              0               0                   3
...  
...
```

The position of values in `Category_2005` (and also in other columns) doesn't matter, just have to check whether values are present in target table i.e. `CoAuthor_Areas` or not, if one value matches, then value for column `Similarity` in table `Yearly_Author_CoAuthors` (which is base table from which to take Author and their CoAuthor yearly basis) will be `Low`, if 2 values get matched, then `Medium` and if three values get matched then `High`. Moreover, if no values get matched, then `Deviant`.

Whereas I have tried this but not getting as desired.

```
SELECT AA.Category_2005 [Author_2005], CA.Category_2005 [CoAuthor_2005],
AA.Rank [AA_Rank], CA.Rank [CA_Rank]
FROM Author_Areas AA
JOIN CoAuthor_Areas CA ON AA.Category_2005 IN (CA.Category_2005)
WHERE CA.co_aid = (SELECT CoAuthor 
                   FROM Yearly_Author_CoAuthors
                   WHERE Year = 2005 AND
                   Author = 677
                  )
AND AA.aid = 677  
ORDER BY AA.Rank, CA.Rank
```

which gives this output:

```
Author_2005   CoAuthor_2005   AA_Rank   CA_Rank
-----------------------------------------------
8             8               1         2
11            11              2         1
12            12              3         3
```

Whereas `CoAuthor_2005` should be as 11, 8, 12. And also how to check as all values here get matched and have to write `High` in `Similarity` column of `Yearly_Author_CoAuthors` table. (I'm unable to sort out how to count number of matches in respective columns and then to write `High`, `Medium`, `Low` or `Deviant` in `Similarity` column.

The `Yearly_Author_CoAuthors` table structure is:

```
Author  CoAuthor    Year    Similarity
--------------------------------------
677     901706      2005    High
677     838459      2007    ???
677     901706      2007    Low
677     1695352     2007    ???  
...  
...  
677     210628      2014    High  
...  
...
```

I have added dummy values in `Yearly_Author_CoAuthors` as it will be `High` if all 3 values get matched, it'll be `Medium` if 2 values get matched, `Low` if 1 value get matched and `Deviant` if none of values get matched. How can we match these columns as desired?

Comment: where you define 'low', 'medium' ... in your above query? show structure of restrant table? and define which match will go to low, medium, high etc.

Comment: @Ajay2707 I have added `Resultant` table structure and also rules for `High`, `Medium` and `Low` matches

Comment: Its not understandable, good to use actual tablename rather than a , c, resultant. also in Resultant table structure, Resultant  column you display. Edit your question as first you define your input tables list with data, then give your query with actual name , then give the output of result with logic where you are going wrong. Then we able to help you

Comment: @Ajay2707 I have added information as asked. Is it enough to sort out my problem

Comment: Pls give your expect result

Comment: @NguyễnHảiTriều I have depicted the result in `Similarity` column of `Yearly_Author_CoAuthors` table. That is what I want to write `High`, `Medium`, `Low` or `Deviant` after matching respective columns of `Author_Areas` table with `CoAuthor_Areas` table

Comment: @NguyễnHảiTriều No, its a range of 2005-2014 years, dots showing it

Comment: @NguyễnHảiTriều I have tried a query for just only one year because unable to figure out the actual way to meet the road

Comment: I see, but I not clear at: high, low,...

Comment: Does each co_aid just have 3 values of rank (1,2,3)?

Comment: @NguyễnHảiTriều High means, for year 2005 all three values get matched as you can see in `Author_Areas` values are 8, 11, 12 and in `CoAuthor_Areas` values are 11, 8, 12 mean all are same so I have placed `High` in `Similarity` column

Comment: @NguyễnHảiTriều yes each co_aid have same or less number of values for rank (1,2,3)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97589/discussion-between-taufel-and-nguyn-hi-triu).